# How to get jQuery Ajax call to post to Action decorated with ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, action

In one of my Controller, the Action Method is not getting executed if I decorate it with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

**More info**: I have the razor code to generate the token that I have retrieved from a hidden field. I have incorporated it in my jQuery Ajax call (which passes a model and another value to the controller action (`AccountController.Login`). It never executes that action. What am I missing here?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     ...std MVC Identity Login code..
}
```

Markup in the Login view  (i.e. no  tag)  (which is in JQuery modal)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
    <div>...login markup</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function ()
            {
                var modeldata = { Email: $('#txtUserEmail').val(), Password: $('#txtPwd').val() };
                var returnUrl = null;

                var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

                alert(token);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Account/Login",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: modeldata, returnUrl: returnUrl },
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'JSON', //do not use JSON , because the server is expecting the __RequestVerificationToken parameter to be part of the POST request payload
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',

                    success: function (ViewResult)
                    {
                        if (ViewResult === "0")
                        {
                            window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#dialogL').replaceWith(ViewResult);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are the backticks in `$('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')` a typo?

Comment: `contentType` is what you're sending, so I guess it should be "application/json" not xml. `dataType` is what you get as response, it's set to json but according to the code it is a string (not sure if that's an issue here). Also you need to call stringify before sending `data`. Hope it helps but there might be more issues there.

Comment: @derloopkat, No, it need to be the default `contentType` and not stringified

Comment: @Stephen Muecke
Yup they are a typo,..came from copy n pasting, have removed them now.

Comment: @derloopkat tried your suggestions as well, however still not executing the Action

Comment: None of this makes any sense. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page, but you are redirecting using `location.href` - Do not use ajax is you want to redirect. (in any case, if you have generated the view correctly, then to serialize the form, you just use `$('form').serialize()` which includes the token

Comment: @Stephen Muecke
Unfortunately this is a requirement, as this system requires a Dynamic Nav Menu, based on the User's successful login credentials, so case - SignInStatus.Success, binds the menu on the user role.
HTH Thx

Comment: That has nothing to do with making an ajax call

Comment: oh,..and the Menu provides for Login initially, and after successful login, displays the appropriate menus, and toggles Login to Logoff. The Login is thus displayed with jquery Modal and ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174257/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-neal-rogers).